# How to get the function arguments value?

Tags: javascript

I want to simplify my email validation by looping through all the function arguments value using arguments[i] but it returns "undefined".

```
function checkInputRequired(companyNameValue, contactNameValue, publisherEmailValue, publisherEmailConfirmValue)
    {
        // The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        {
            // print out 4 undefined
            console.log(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which arguments are you testing with? Don’t tell me, you don’t provide any arguments…

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
function checkInputRequired(companyNameValue, contactNameValue, publisherEmailValue, publisherEmailConfirmValue)
    {
        // The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        {
            // print out 4 undefined
            console.log(arguments[i]);
        }
    }

checkInputRequired('ddd','bbbbb','sssss','dddddddddd');
```

when you call the function it will display the values otherwise it show the default value undefined.

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir haha thanks. Actually, I structured my code in a wrong way. It's not grabbing the .val() on form submit and I assumed that I passed in the values correctly and I thought it was something to do with arguments object. Case closed.